Access domain through another server (like tunneling?)
Is it possible, to route all traffic to and from abc.com on vserver-A through vserver-B?

vserver-A and vserver-B are both simple debian VMs on the internet

vserver-A should normally use the internet directly BUT if a request goes to abc.com it should access it through vserver-B so that

vserver-A is only calling vserver-B to the public
abc.com see's only vserver-B's address

I know I can tunnel all traffic simply through ssh-tunneling and a socks proxy setup, but this should only be domain-specific?

not by "domain" per se, but definitely by subnet via the IP routing table. eg: 123.123.123.0/24 uses one gateway, and 0.0.0.0/0 uses another.

but what if the domain can have different IPs? And on time of request I don't know the IP yet.

is this primarily for a HTTP based (browser-based) application?

No, I need it for a bash script.

Thats too bad, because I can think of a way to do it with a proxy server and a proxy auto-config script, but whatever application that is using it needs to support proxy configuration and auto-configuration scripts, which most do not (but browsers do). remember most applications don't transmit domain names as part of their data, so the only thing that interacts with the domain name is the application itself. http traffic contains the url with domain, but most other apps just do a dns lookup, and then send IP traffic to the destination, so no upstream sys could decide what to do on domain name.

what application are you calling within your script (netcat, curl, wget, etc) and what protocol is the remote endpoint listening for?

Thanks for your ideas. I think its more convenient to route all traffic through that middle-man, then. But to answer your questions: using cURL via TCP on port 443.

Another way would be to simply call server-b directly, not asking for the real target domain but send a custom header, that tells server-a to proxy this traffic to the final domain.

ok it looks like curl will not support proxy PAC files so you won;t be able to selectively engage the proxy that way. oh well. https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/proxies/pac.html . I don't think your custom header idea will work because the proxy server will still route traffic by IP, so the network path still won't be determined by domain name. what specific proxy server are you wanting to use?
